# ChartJS 2.0 animation

Tags: javascript, animation, charts, chart.js

I've run into a problem using ChartJS 2.2.1 when I tried to build timeline chart (line chart + time option).

### Approach 1: Wrong animation

I request new value from server ( in format [time,value] ) every 5 seconds and I want only 10 points on screen, so, when new data come in, I:

- remove oldest point from chart
- add new point

The problem here is animation - chart not shifts to the left - it's just redraws on the same place.

### Approach 2: Bad at all

My solution to get this 'shift' animation is add data to chart, moving min and max time values to keep only 10 values on screen (without removing it):

```
    line_chart.chart.config.data.datasets[0].data.push({x: moment.utc(time).toDate(), y: value});
    line_chart.update();

    line_chart.config.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.min = line_chart.chart.config.data.datasets[0].data[line_chart.chart.config.data.datasets[0].data.length - onscreen_points].x;
    line_chart.config.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.max = moment.utc(time).toDate();
```

I guess that's not the best idea and I've already had some troubles with this approach.
Is here any other solution?

P.S. In ChartJS 1.0 this 'shift' animation works well with first approach.